# jQuery not updating CSS properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble figuring out why the CSS `color` and 'text-decoration' properties are not being applied via the 'menulight' function I have here.

The 'font-weight' and 'font-family' are working fine when I hover over the menu items.

I cut out the rest of the code that the other functions are being applied to just to keep this concise.

**Edit:** Added the rest of the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Meetings &#038; Events | The Landon Hotel</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
<script src="../../jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("div.event").hover(highlight);
        $("#menu-main-menu a").hover(menulight);
    });
    function highlight(evt) {
        $(this).toggleClass("divhover");
    }
    function menulight(evt) {
        $(this).toggleClass("menuhover");
    }
</script>
    <style type='text/css'>

        .divhover {
            background-color:cornsilk;
        }
        .divhover .eventDate {
            text-decoration: underline;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: times new roman;
            color:magenta;
        }
        .menuhover  {
            font-weight: bold;
            color:magenta;
            font-family: cursive;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header"><img src="img/header.png"></div>
        <div id="hero">
            <div class="current"><img src="img/HomePageImages/Paris.jpg"></div>
        </div>
    <nav class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <div>
            <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav-menu">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="restaurant-to-room-service.html">Room Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="specials.html">Specials</a></li>
                <li><a href="reservations.html">Reservations</a></li>
                <li><a href="meetings-events.html">Meetings &#038; Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="content">

        <h1>Meetings &#038; Events</h1>
        <p>All of the following meetings take place in the Bernal Height Landon Hotel in San Francisco, in their new, state-of the-art conference room.</p>
        <hr/>

        <div class="event">
        <h3>23rd Annual Inventors International Exhibition and Conference:</h3>
        <img width="220px" src="img/inventors_international.jpg"> 
        <ul><li id="eventDate" class="eventDate">Friday, October 31st through Sunday, November 2nd 2014</li></ul>
        <p>The best scientific minds, showing their riveting and forward-thinking inventions, will be in-house for a science and technology-packed weekend. The halls, conference room, and lobby of the Bernal Heights Landon Hotel will be brimming with exhibits, presentations, and demonstrations - providing something for everyone in the family.</p>        
        </div>

        <div class="event">
        <h3>KinetEco, Inc. Solar Seminar:</h3>
        <img class="meeting-right" src="img/solar_conference.jpg"> 
        <ul><li class="eventDate">Friday, November 7th through Sunday, November 9th 2014</li></ul> 
        <p>San Francisco's own KinetEco, Inc. has been a trailblazer in solar energy for the past two decades, and has solarized thousands of businesses and residences throughout the world. Join their talented team of engineers and scientists for this not-to-be-missed event that will explore solar as the must-have energy source of the present and future.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="event">
        <h3>Classic Car Social:</h3> 
        <img class="meeting-left" src="img/classic_car.jpg">
        <ul><li class="eventDate">Tuesday, November 11th through Wednesday, November 12th  2014</li></ul>
        <p>Join other classic car enthusiasts for the monthly classic car social. Bring your car to showcase and share your hobby with others, and enjoy a hearty breakfast buffet. Reservations are required, as parking space is limited for the event.</p>  
        </div>

        <div class="event">
        <h3>Hansel &#038; Petal California Native Gardening Seminar:</h3>
        <img class="meeting-right" src="img/california_natives.jpg">
        <ul><li class="eventDate">Friday, November 21st through Sunday, November 23rd 2014</li></ul>
        <p>With California's current drought situation, never has it been timelier to attend one of Hansel &#038; Petal's informative seminars on native gardening. You'll learn how to select and layout plants for an attractive and drought-resistant landscape. In addition, a tour of some of the best local native gardens will be offered on Saturday morning.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have jQuery library included?

Comment: Are you sure `$(this)` refers to an element and not to the `window` object?

Comment: yes I do have a jquery library included, here I will just add the entire page code just for clarity.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something I'm not sure it is neccessary to do this via JS when CSS can handle :hover, :focus styles of anchors, etc. e.g .event:hover { background:... } .event:hover .eventDate { }.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `#menulight a` has a higher precedence in CSS than the class selector `.menuhover`. The fact that font-weight and font-family can be overridden is indicative of this, as these properties were not declared in the selector with the higher preference. You should use `#menu-main-menu a.menuhover` instead:

```
    #menu-main-menu a {
        color: green;
    }
    #menu-main-menu a.menuhover  {
        font-weight: bold;
        color:magenta;
        font-family: cursive;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

Comment: Well the class is being toggled so I thought that wouldn't matter? Also , why does text-decoration not work?

Comment: I see what you're saying I think . Thank you!

Comment: It does matter: a toggled class is being treated the same as any classes, and standard CSS precedence calculation will take place. Unless you are overriding using `.css()`, which writes the style inline. Inline styles have higher precedence than any properties declared in the stylesheets except those with the `!important` suffixes. Are there alternative stylesheets loaded specifying the anchor element text-decoration property?

Comment: Ah yes okay. And if you don't mind. I tried removing  #menu-main-menu a {
        color: green;
    }      and leaving the original code, and even without that higher precedent selector, the color and text-decoration didnt work. Any idea?

Comment: This could help you: https://specificity.keegan.st/ - `#menu-main-menu a` has `0-1-0-1` and `.menuhover` has `0-0-1-0` which is lower specificty than the first.

Comment: Yes, totally understand now. But even if I removed that #menu-main-menu selector, and just left the .menuhover selector, the color and text-decoration still didnt work. You know what I mean? LIke even without the higher precedent selector overriding it.

Comment: There is also an external style sheet. :link, :visited, :hover, :focus, etc. can also keep some higher specificity if they were included there for anchors. So you might potentially have to add some specificity for those as well when you run into them.

Comment: Ah I see, didn't know that. I guess I just gotta be specific with selectors even if in the case that I don't explicitly use a higher precedent one.